# How to find out if any row at any level or group in Janus Grid is expanded or not?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, janus

I am trying to implement Collapse All / Expand ALL button on a Janus Grid in C# but there is no point in showing Collapse ALL when there is nothing to collapse!

So i need a way to find out if there is any row at some level is NOT expanded so that i can show and enable the Expand ALL button.

I am hoping for a way other that iterating down through all the rows and verifying if some random child row is not expanded.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no such built in method. My suggestion if it is important that you don't use recursion is to utlize the `RowCollapsed` and `RowExpanded` events in conjuction with a `HashSet<GridEXRow>` to register and unregister rows that get expanded/collapsed.

```
public class ...
{
    ...
    HashSet<GridEXRow> expandedRows = new HashSet<GridEXRow>();

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return expandedRows.Count > 0; }
    }
    ...

    private void gridEX_RowCollapsed(object sender, Janus.Windows.GridEX.RowActionEventArgs e)
    {
        expandedRows.Remove(e.Row);
    }

    private void gridEXLocation_RowExpanded(object sender, Janus.Windows.GridEX.RowActionEventArgs e)
    {
        expandedRows.Add(e.Row);
    }
}
```

Note that using this method there could be a performance hit when you Expand all (all rows added to expandedRows) and collapse. Collapse all would clear expandedRows, however when collapsing all you would still trigger `RowCollapsed` for each row e.g. theres no such shortcut as doing `expandedRows.Clear();` without first removing the event and then putting it back again.